# Write to clipboard in java and excel export link

Tags: java, excel

In excel you can copy a cell and paste it in another using the excel paste special from the right click menu.
How can I write such a link in java to paste in excel?

Comment: A link meaning like a formula `=SUM(A2:A6)`?

Answer (score 1):

Its too broad a question. What lib do you use to working with Excel? For example, using [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) you can just read cell to java object and save to new place (all values, or just, for instance, formulas or text only). A lot of example, to working with Excel you can found [this](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html)

Comment: Broad not board, 'its too broad of a question`

Comment: sorry, I fixed my post

Comment: No worries, I could barely learn basic french so id say you're doing a good job